# How can I display a multicast video stream in a React.js web application using FFmpeg and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, ffmpeg, multicast

I'm working on a project where I'm sending video using the following FFmpeg command:
`ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HP Wide Vision HD Camera" -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuvj420p -level:v 4.1 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -r 10 -b:v 512k -s 640x360 -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 32k -ar 44100 -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://235.235.235.235:12345` 
My goal is to display the sent video using JavaScript and React. Is this possible, and how can it be accomplished?

I tried using the video.js library, but I received the following error:
`video.es.js:218 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:2 MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK) HLS playlist request error at URL: udp://235.235.235.235:12345.`
This is the code I wrote:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import videojs from "video.js";

import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const videoElement = videoRef.current;
    const options = {
      techOrder: ["html5"],
      sources: [
        {
          src: "udp://235.235.235.235:12345",
          type: "application/x-mpegURL",
        },
      ],
    };

    const player = videojs(videoElement, options);

    return () => {
      if (player) {
        player.dispose();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} className="video-js vjs-default-skin" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

import React from "react";
import VideoPlayer from "./VideoPlayer.js";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Displaying Multicast Stream</h1>
      <VideoPlayer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Are there any other pre-built libraries available that I can use for this purpose? If not, what alternatives or options might be available? Thank you in advance!